# How to cache node code which executes and then exits

Tags: node.js, database, caching

In Node, normally I cache on my server using an in-memory cache or a database or using Lodash memoize. This is easy since the process never exits.

However, when running some node code which executes and then exits, how do I cache values so that when the same code is executed much later it remembers the values it previously retrieved without having to retrieve them from file again (which takes about 2 seconds and is too slow)?

An outline of the program is:

(1) Read some files and extract 6 million numbers // NEED THE CACHING HERE

(2) Return those numbers in an array

(3) Process exits

I know I could use a database but not sure I want the complications of setting up a database for such a simple bit of code.

I could use file caching, but I'm not sure that writing the 6 million values to file and then reading them in every time thereafter is going to improve performance.

I don't think I can use an in-memory cache since the memory is wiped when the process exits? right?

Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: How about some database? Redis?

Comment: I think you need to rephrase the question to "how to avoid reading 6 million records on each load"

Comment: Is Redis dead easy to set up?

Comment: @danday74 something like Redis or Memcached would be the way to go here

Comment: Depends on your environment. Locally you can use a docker and a node module (with copy/paste examples).. so yes it should be easy. Production - use a DB service (I bet there's a redis too) - for easiness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave the node process running and then keep everything cached in memory. Then using something along the lines of `express` (RESTful) or `socket.io` (over socket) you can relay the records to the consumer.

---

For npm package

DanPlugin.js

```
let data;
module.exports = function expensiveGetData() {
   if(data) return data;
   // do expensive read
   data = ...the result;
}
```

DanPluginConsumer.js

```
const DanPlugin = require('DanPlugin');
data = DanPlugin();


.... some time later
data2 = DanPlugin(); // fast
```

Comment: will work I know, but overkill for what I want, +1 anyway for trying :)

Comment: @danday74 what's the consumer of your node process?

Comment: the function will be exposed in an npm package, anyone whose got the npm package installed can consume / call it

Comment: oh why not just store it in a variable. If the file is required multiple times in the same app I believe it should keep its state of the variables (see above)

Comment: see what you're saying, will give it a whirl - altho I'm leaning toward a db to avoid the initial slow call - much appreciated